# how to add ftp users to an apache from PHP?

Tags: php, apache, shell, ftp, batch-file

how do i go about adding ftp users to an apache web server? i need the user to register from normal web/script and then have an FTP account set up for them automatically.

I have seen the cPanel API, and it is pretty decent, but since cPanel costs money, i don't wish to use it for this project. I'm also reluctant to use any other lisenced piece of software.

i want to be able to do it using shell/batch (or pure PHP, though that hardly seem plausible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you said Apache is a *Web* and not an FTP Server. But most FTP servers like e.g. [PureFtpd](http://www.pureftpd.org/) offer [MySQL authentication](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.MySQL). So you just have to modify the authentication table with PHP to add new users.

Comment: thanks a lot. pureftpd looks cool, but i'm not sure the avarage host has it. i would like to collect some more thoughts from everyone before i close the question.